# Removed or change unity 5 default splash screen "Made with unity"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

Is there any way available to remove unity 5 default splash screen which comes after building standalone player? and is this legal?

Comment: I agree with Greg: the spash screen is automatically removed if you have a Pro License. Using the free version, there's no legal way to remove it.

Comment: thanks @Andrea i got the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I got it in **buildSettings**.-> Player setting(button)-> on Inspector I got the option. **unchecked**

Note: This feature is not available(or active) in Unity Personal version, as **Greg Zetko** answer suggested.

Comment: It is a `must mention`, that it depends on the license, he must have one of the paid plans to be able to use that option.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the license that you have(ex. Pro/Personal).

Please refer to [UNITY PRO AND UNITY PERSONAL SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT 5.X](https://unity3d.com/legal/eula)

> Although Unity Personal has most of the features and functionality that Unity Pro has, Unity Personal: (a) includes certain features that cannot be disabled when your application is launched, including a **Unity branded startup** screen and certain analytics data collection;

Comment: Thanks for giving valuable  input

Comment: No problem. Did it help?